# Spidermonkey dotnet build with --enable-trace-jscalls

Tags: c#, javascript, spidermonkey

I have a problem concerning spidermonkey dotnet - http://spidermonkeydotnet.codeplex.com/

Spidermonkey dotnet is a wrapper between Spidermonkey (JavaScript Engine - Mozilla) and C# ...
I want to use the `JS_SetFunctionCallback` from Spidermonkey to use my program as a profiler for JavaScript ...

I have built the JavaScript Engine on my Windows 7 Notebook with `--enable-trace-jscalls`.
My problem is that can't implement it in Spidermonkey dotnet.

In VS2010 it says that:

> "The identifier cannot be found!"

I have included the headers in Spidermonkey dotnet but I get the same issue.